# SPI conflict between SD.h and U8x8.h (LCD)

Tags: display, arduino-uno, sd-card, spi

I want to reproduce a .wav file on my Arduino Uno via an SD card while at the same time using an LCD display (Nokia 5110). I'm having trouble trying to make the double SPIs work and since I'm not really familiar with the libraries that I used I decided to ask for help

The problem is that once the program execute *SD.begin()* the display stops working and the SPI communication is working only on the SD.

In this setup that I'm showing I will initialize the SD in the setup() and in the loop using a button I'm supposed to write stuff on the display:

```
//Libraries
  #include <U8x8lib.h>
  #include <SPI.h>
  #include "SD.h"
  #include "TMRpcm.h"

  //Display                         (pin 13,  pin 11,  pin A1, pin 12, pin A0 )
    U8X8_PCD8544_84X48_4W_SW_SPI lcd(LCD_CLK, LCD_DIN, LCD_CE, LCD_DC, LCD_RST); 

  //Speaker
    TMRpcm music;


void setup() {
  
  //Serial port -> Open
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {}

  //LCD
    display_setup();

  //SD and Speaker
    sdAndSpeaker_setup();

}

void loop() {

  topButton.poll();
  if (topButton.buttonClicked) {
    display_something();  
  }
  
}
```

Ignore the function related to the button, I removed most of its code to avoid cluttering the page.

Here's when the problem occurs:

```
void sdAndSpeaker_setup() {

    music.speakerPin = 10;
//               (pin 4)
    if (!SD.begin(SD_CS)) {
    Serial.println("SD fail");
    Serial.flush();
    abort();
    }
    
    music.setVolume(4);
    music.play("Daybreak.wav");
    music.quality(2);
    
}
```

I know that by changing the pins of display to other value (rather than 11, 12 and 13) the problems is solved but most of the pins in my board are already used and I don't have this luxury... I think this has something to do with the U8x8.h and SD.h library but I don't have the skills to tweak those.

If anyone has a suggestion I'll appreciate!
Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks to Juraj for the clarification, here's my new changes for the corrected constructor:

```
U8X8_PCD8544_84X48_4W_HW_SPI lcd(LCD_CE, LCD_DC, LCD_RST);
```

And for the setup_display()

```
void display_setup() {
  
  lcd.begin();

  pinMode(LCD_LIGHT, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LCD_LIGHT, HIGH);

  lcd.setFont(u8x8_font_chroma48medium8_r);
  lcd.drawString(1,2, "Hello!");
}
```

Unfortunately it still doesn't work...

Comment: add a link to the library you use. usually if you specify SPI pins, the library has software SPI. see if the library has a constructor which doesn't want SPI pins. it will use the SPI library for hardware SPI and then it can work with the SD card. note: many SD modules have not suitable logic level conversion which blocks the bus for other devices. other option is to use the software SPI of the display library, but then don't use the hardware SPI pins for it.

Comment: Display library: https://github.com/olikraus/u8g2
SD library: https://github.com/arduino-libraries/SD
For the SPI I'm not sure, it's probably build in since I can't find the file in my computer.

I heard it can be a problem of the physical module, would you suggest me to buy a new one?

Comment: check your SD module. is the MISO line connected to level shifter chip or directly to the SD card?

Comment: It is a 3.3V module, so no level shifter. I take directly the 3.3V output of the Uno

Comment: for Uno you must have a logic level conversion on SCK and MOSI. the SD card can't take 5 V

Comment: Yes for those pins there are a couple resistors inside the module that do the job. The level shifter (and voltage regulator) are usually present inside the 5V module for the Vdd pin

Comment: @Luca Im having same issue. Did you find out?

Comment: No, unfortunately I had to change library. Now I use the: <NOKIA5110_TEXT.h>. Same features I needed though I had to modify the SPI_FREQ variable in the library to make it work with my clock.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor

```
 U8X8_PCD8544_84X48_4W_SW_SPI(uint8_t clock, uint8_t data, uint8_t cs, uint8_t dc, uint8_t reset = U8X8_PIN_NONE)
```

creates a 'driver' which uses software SPI. But you supply pins of hardware SPI as parameters. Hardware SPI is used by the SD library over the SPI library to access the SD card, so **hardware SPI conflicts with the software SPI of the display library**.

There is a

```
U8X8_PCD8544_84X48_4W_HW_SPI(uint8_t cs, uint8_t dc, uint8_t reset = U8X8_PIN_NONE)
```

constructor which uses the hardware SPI over the SPI library. The SPI library 'knows' the pin numbers of the SPI pins. (SPI library is part of the boards package. It can't be installed separately.)

If you want to use the software SPI, use free pins. The hardware SPI uses pins 11, 12, 13 on Uno.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I went through a bit of the library and I think I understand what I was doing wrong, however when I change the constructor the way you've told me I'm still not able to use the lcd.drawString() func.

I'll update the question now!

Comment: @Luca, what pins do you use. LCD_DC was pin 12 in your sketch. is the wiring right for hw SPI?

Comment: I double checked, unfortunately every wire is connected properly... Now I've stripped everything but the display to debug, I'll keep this question updated once I find a solution!